# How to receive model properties from a model deployed via Azure OpenAI

Tags: python, azure, openai-api, azure-openai

I want to get the properties of a model, which is deployed in Azure OpenAI like the ones shown in the screenshot.
[image]

How can I receive them in Python? I searched for it, but I can't find an answer or I'm asking the wrong question. It doesn't seem to be such a big problem and O hope someone can help me.

I just searched for an answer, but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the properties of a model, which is deployed in Azure OpenAI using Python.

You can use the below Python code to get the **`properties`** of Azure Open-AI deployments using Azure Python SDK.

**Code:**

```
from azure.mgmt.cognitiveservices import CognitiveServicesManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = CognitiveServicesManagementClient(credential, subscription_id="subscriptionId")

deployment =client.deployments.get(resource_group_name="resourceGroupName", account_name="accountName", deployment_name="deploymentName")
properties = deployment.properties

print("Model name:", properties.model.name)
print("Model version:", properties.model.version)
print("Tokens per Minute Rate Limit (thousands):",properties.rate_limits[0].count)
print("Rate limit (Tokens per minute):",properties.rate_limits[1].count)
print("Rate limit (Requests per minute):", properties.rate_limits[0].count * 6)
```

**Output:**

```
Model name: xxx
Model version: 1
Tokens per Minute Rate Limit (thousands): 33.0
Rate limit (Tokens per minute): 33000.0
Rate limit (Requests per minute): 198.0
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Deployments - Get - REST API (Azure Cognitive Services) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/accountmanagement/deployments/get?view=rest-cognitiveservices-accountmanagement-2023-05-01&tabs=Python#getdeployment)

Comment: That was helpful, thank you :)